# Aws: best approach to process data from S3 to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl

I'm trying to implement, I think, a very simple process, but I don't really know what's the best approach.

I want to read a big csv (around 30gb) file from S3, make some transformation and load it into RDS MySQL and I want this process to be replicable.

I tought that the best approach was Aws data pipeline, but I've found that this service is more designed to load data from different sources to redshift after several transformtions.
I've also seen that the process of creating a pipeline is slow and a little bit messy.
Then I've found the dataduct wrapper of Coursera, but after some research, it seems that this project has been abandoned (the last commit was one year ago).

So I don't know if I should continue trying with aws data pipeline or take another approach.

I've also read about AWS Simple Workflow and Step Functions, but I don't know if it's simpler.
Then I've seen a video of AWS glue and it looks nice, but unfortunatelly it's not yet available and I don't know when Amazon will launch it.

As you see, I'm a little bit confuse, can anyone enlight me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Data Pipeline existed way before Redshift, so I'm not sure why you think it is designed mainly for loading data into Redshift. I do agree that building a pipeline is slow and messy. Any reason you are using RDS MySQL instead of RDS Aurora? Aurora has the ability to load data directly from CSV files in S3 (similar to Redshift).

Comment: I tought that because almost all the premade templates and examples involved loading into Redshift. Aurora as MySQL can load directly a csv, the problem is that I need to transform the data before loading.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get them into RDS so you can query them, there are other options that do not require the data to be moved from S3 to RDS to do SQL like queries.

You can use [Redshift spectrum](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-getting-started-using-spectrum.html) to read and query information from S3 now.

> Using Amazon Redshift Spectrum, you can efficiently query and retrieve structured and semistructured data from files in Amazon S3 without having to load the data into Amazon Redshift tables

Step 1. Create an IAM Role for Amazon Redshift

Step 2: Associate the IAM Role with Your Cluster

Step 3: Create an External Schema and an External Table

Step 4: Query Your Data in Amazon S3

Or you can use [Athena](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/getting-started.html) to query the data in S3 as well if Redshift is too much horsepower for the need job.

> Amazon Athena is an interactive query service that makes it easy to analyze data directly in Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) using standard SQL.

Comment: Nice to know, but I really need to load the data into a relational database in RDS MySql, and I need this process to be replicable in the future. I need that because of an application requirements, ;-).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ETL tool to do the transformations on your csv data and then load it into your RDS database.  There are a number of open source tools that do not require large licensing costs.  That way you can pull the data into the tool, do your transformations and then the tool will load the data into your MySQL database. For example there is Talend, Apache Kafka, and Scriptella.  Here's some [information](https://blog.panoply.io/11-great-etl-tools-and-the-case-for-saying-no-to-etl) on them for comparison.

I think Scriptella would be an option for this situation.  It can use SQL scripts (or other scripting languages), and has JDBC/ODBC compliant drivers.  With this you could create a script that would perform your transformations and then load the data into your MySQL database.  And you would be using familiar SQL (I'm assuming you already can create SQL scripts) so there isn't a big learning curve.